# Console styling not working in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

I am attempting to use console styling for some debugging but running into something strange - it is simply not working. :(

**Example code** (from https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-write#styling_console_output_with_css)

```
console.log("%cThis will be formatted with large, blue text", "color: blue; font-size: x-large");
```

Looks like this in the console:

> %cThis will be formatted with large, blue text color: blue; font-size: x-large

Am I doing something wrong? Is there some `Chrome` setting I'm missing or have set incorrectly?

Comment: Version of Chrome?

Comment: The given code snippet seems to work for me.

Comment: works in multiple browsers for me

Comment: Maybe you've redefined `console.log`. What does `console.log(console.log)` show?

Comment: Works for me too. Now I know how facebook is able to stylize their console logs. Neat trick.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone that responded.

My Chrome version was 63.(other numbers) (64-bit)

When I went to Chrome About to get this information, it let me know that my version was out of date and to update and relaunch.

I did and now my version is: Version 64.0.3282.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)

... and now it works. :/

My best guess is that there was something in that version of 63 (64-bit) that had the issue and they found it (or monitor StackOverflow?) :)